# Unable to cast music to Chromecast

Tags: ios, objective-c, chromecast

I'm trying to establish a simple audio stream to a Chromecast device. This is just a POC for me to familiarize myself with the API. What I want to do is load up the user's library, select a song, and have it cast over. I've been following the [integration guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate) quite closely but to no avail.

Please find the full project on Github [here](https://github.com/mootjeuh/Stackoverflow-Cast).

An overview of my code, **AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    GCKCastOptions *options = [GCKCastOptions.alloc initWithReceiverApplicationID:kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID];

    [GCKCastContext setSharedInstanceWithOptions:options];
    [GCKCastContext.sharedInstance.sessionManager addListener:self];
}
```

**UITableViewDelegate**:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
MPMediaItem *mediaItem = MusicManager.sharedManager[index];
    NSString *path = [MPMediaLibrary.defaultMediaLibrary pathForAssetURL:mediaItem.assetURL];

    GCKMediaMetadata *metadata = [GCKMediaMetadata.alloc initWithMetadataType:GCKMediaMetadataTypeMusicTrack];

    [metadata setString:mediaItem.title forKey:kGCKMetadataKeyTitle];
    [metadata setString:mediaItem.artist forKey:kGCKMetadataKeyArtist];
    [metadata setString:mediaItem.albumTitle forKey:kGCKMetadataKeyAlbumTitle];

    GCKMediaInformation *mediaInfo = [GCKMediaInformation.alloc initWithContentID:path
                                                                       streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeBuffered
                                                                      contentType:[self fileMIMEType:path]
                                                                         metadata:metadata
                                                                   streamDuration:mediaItem.playbackDuration
                                                                       customData:nil];

    [GCKCastContext.sharedInstance.sessionManager.currentCastSession.remoteMediaClient loadMedia:mediaInfo autoplay:YES];
}
```

I initiate the casting session by tapping the `GCKCastButton` and Start Session, my TV shows the Cast logo, then when I tap on a specific song, my TV briefly shows the metadata (i.e. song title, artist name, etc.), and then reverts back to the Chromecast logo. On the device, if I remain on the screen presented by `GCKCastButton`, I can also see the details of the song that is supposed to be currently casting, but quickly changes to "No Media Selected" after a few seconds.

I've checked the file path, the MIME type, everything is correct and playable. I've even tried bundling a short MP3 and trying to cast that, but to no avail.

Can't help but feel like I'm missing something here, the integration guide doesn't really give much more info.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was under the wrong impression that the cast library initiates a stream from the provided file itself. But instead it required an actual URL for the Chromecast device to perform a GET operation on.

I imagine this will be solved by running a server locally on the iOS device.

Comment: Confirmed. [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) did the trick quite well.